# How to convert HTML file to string in React Native?

Tags: react-native

How do I take an HTML file inside my project and convert it into a string? I have tried using react-native-fs but that is looking for files on the device while this file will be inside of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Just download HTML with fetch(), parse it using fast-html-parser, write result to state and render that state with WebView